# Image comparison or processing library in python?

Tags: python, computer-vision, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to develop a small program to compare if there's a car in a parking lot.

For example this picture: [image]

I want to be able to compare where there's a car and where there isn't one. Is there a library that allows me to do that type of comparison? The image I'll be comparing might be a bit closer to the cars, but I don't know cause I don't have it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have no prior experience with OpenCV I'd start with [SimpleCV](http://simplecv.org/). It is built on top of OpenCV but is much easier to use

Comment: And by lucky coincidence [`SimpleCV`](http://tutorial.simplecv.org/en/latest/examples/parking.html) has a tutorial on ["Detecting a car in a parking lot"](http://tutorial.simplecv.org/en/latest/examples/parking.html)

Comment: yes!!! this is soooo much easier. I haven't tried it. I need to get a raspberry pi, but I will when I do. Thanks, bros. I had red about a trainer and but I wasn't really getting it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at the OpenCV library, which has Python bindings.

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html

OpenCV is a "computer vision" library, and it is intended for the sort of thing you want to do.  As far as I know, it's the most widely-used computer vision library, and it's BSD-licensed so you will be able to do anything you want with it.

http://opencv.org/

http://opencv.org/about.html

Comment: nice, I'll look that up. Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

I think an opensource library [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/) might be your friend. It is an alternative to OpenCV python API.

Comment: [`scikit-image`](http://scikit-image.org/) also has lots of great examples with both images and code: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/

Comment: yeah, thanks I was trying out opencv and it's a bit complicated lol

Answer (score 0):

If it's a video I would recommend you to look at this:
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_video/py_bg_subtraction/py_bg_subtraction.html#py-background-subtraction

It shows how to distinguish the background from passing items.